# Django form DateTimeField initial value is blank

Tags: python, django-forms, timezone, hidden-field

I have a create form in which I'm submitting the field ['created_at'] as a hidden datetimefield. I'm importing from django.utils import timezone and have this working on another model. Does anyone have any insight into why the value is blank? Thanks for any help!

form:

```
class CreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ('name', 'course', 'core', 'animal_group', 'image_on', 'image_off', 'created_at',)
        labels = { "image_on": "Animal Image", "image_off": "Incompleted Animal Image", }
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 1}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['created_at'] = forms.DateTimeField(initial = timezone.now())
         self.fields['created_at'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        return cleaned_data
```

However when the templates renders the hidden input is there, but it doesn't have a value. 
[image]

Here is the template code snippet:

```
<form action="/support/add_animal/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ create_form | crispy }}
      <br>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
  </form>
```

Comment: Most likely unrelated - but that is not the recommended way to call clean. Do this instead ```cleaned_data = super(CreateBadgeForm, self).clean()```. There is a section about it here...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: @luke_aus Thanks for the tip!

Comment: did that fix the problem?

Comment: @luke_aus Alas it did not :/ Rather than set the initial value in the form field I updated the model attribute to default=timezone.now().

Comment: the other way to do is it ```def __init__; ...super...; self.initial['myfield'] = timezone.now()``` - this seems to have a higher precedence then ```self.fields['myfield'].initial  = timezone.now()```

Comment: @luke_aus I tried that too! Saw it in another stack answer and thought it was a surefire solution. Oddly enough it didn't change the outcome. Perhaps it's a long shot but I was thinking that my local env wasn't updating with changes I was making? Thought that because honestly everything seemed to point to a functional hidden input - but literally nothing about the output changed when the code did.

Comment: I believe its a django trap to set your model default to ```default=timezone.now()``` - that will instantiate your code in production when the server first loads - so everything will have the same timestamp as timezone.now() for a model field default doesn't ever seem to update. I believe it should be ```default=timezone.now``` - but only when setting model defaults, not for forms.

Comment: @luke_aus Gah, I did leave the parens off of it - just a typo here in the comments. :)

Comment: too easy! You should post your answer than accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than continue banging my head on the wall with this, I opted to set the created_at time in the model rather than worry about it elsewhere.

Set the attribute to have `(default=timezone.now)` and that cured my woes.